# Obtener y reusar un PromiseValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, promesas

El asunto es que necesito obtener un arreglo con los dispositivos de audio/video disponibles, pero la funcion si bien me imprime en la consola un array, no me retorna uno, sino que me retorna una promesa. ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un promiseValue o bien cómo puedo obtener que la funcion miDevices me retorne un arreglo con los dispositvivos disponibles?

```js
var miArrDevices = [];

function miDevices(arr){
 return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(function(res){
   for(var i = 0; i< res.length; i++){
     arr.push(res[i].kind)
    }
    console.log(arr)
    return arr
  })

}
console.log(miDevices(miArrDevices))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No puedes!

Lo que intentas hacer es una accion sincrona, cuando `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` es una accion asincrona.

Ya que retorna una promesa, entonces depende de como el navegador maneje el retorno de los devices en este caso utiliza promesas entonces tu funcion `miDevices` se convierte en una promesa, ya que retornas el valor que te devuelve `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`

Lo que tienes que hacer es esperar a que `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` resuelva los devices

```
var miArrDevices = [];

function miDevices(){
    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(function(res) {
        var arr = [];

        for(var i = 0; i< res.length; i++){
          arr.push(res[i].kind)
        }

        return arr;
    });
}

var devicesPromise = miDevices();

console.log('Devices aun no disponibles: ', miArrDevices);

devicesPromise.then(function(devices) {
  miArrDevices = devices;
  console.log('Devices listo !!! ya se pueden utilizar: ', miArrDevices);
});
```

Comment: Entonces no hay forma de enumerar/enlistar los dispositivos disponibles? :O

Comment: claro que si! pero no de manera sincrona!  ya que `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` te duelve una promesa y lo puedes hacer dentro de la `callback` que retorna `enumerateDevices`

Comment: entiendes la diferencia entre sincrono y asincrono ?

Comment: Si, si entiendo lo de seasincrono. Crees que puedas ayudarme, darme una idea de que otro método o forma podría enlistar los dispositivos?

Comment: Ya se me ocurrió como hacerlo y funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. :D